# como obter um id de uma model em uma view atraves de um link?

Tags: javascript, .net, mvc

Tenho um link que chama uma funcao JS (POPUP), nesse popup eu tenho um FORMULARIO de cadastro,
para  validar todos os parametros do meu form, eu preciso obter o ID da Minha Model que se encontra na view do Link nao estou conseguindo obter esse ID para insercao de dados no BD

Dêem uma olhadinha em meu cod:

view:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Adicionar</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var c in Model.Contactados)
{
 <tr>
   <td>@Html.DisplayFor(cc => c.Nome)</td>
     <td><a class ="chamar" href="#">Adicionar</a></td>        
 </tr>
}
```

formulario que deve receber o ID da view anterior:

```
   @using Forte.Rastreador.ViewModels
@model SuperViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("CadastrarContatoContactado", "Master", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.ValidationSummary(false)

<fieldset>
<legend></legend>
@Html.Label("Contato: ")
@Html.TextBoxFor(c=>c.DescricaoContatoContactado)
@Html.Label("Tipo Contato: ")
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.CodTipoContato, Model.TipoContatoList)
```

```
<input type="submit" value="Adicionar Contato" />

}
```

Comment: Cara, tá meio confuso. Explica melhor ? Você quer obter esse ID no link depois que ele foi cadastrado ?

Comment: sim isso mesmo, nao estou conseguindo obter o id do modelo cadastrado.

Comment: Cara, tente reformular sua pergunta.

Comment: @HansMiller A questão está resolvida? Considere marcar uma resposta como aceita.
*[Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079)*

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Html.HiddenFor(c=>c.Id)` dentro do Form. Assim ele vai ser enviado para o Controller.